# Show only one time a repeat record and all of the other different elements adding to it in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table called `Orders` with 2 attributes: `id_order` and `id_product`.

In this table, I save the list of the products bought adding this to a single id of order, something like this

```
id_order - id_product
1        - 1
1        - 2
1        - 5
1        - 6
2        - 4
2        - 8
2        - 14
3        - 1
```

**I want to show this record in a table, BUT only showing one(1) time the id of order.**

```
 <?php
include "con.php";
$sql       = "SELECT DISTINCT a.id_order , b.id_product FROM orders a JOIN orders b ON a.id_order=b.id_order";
$sentence1 = $con->prepare($sql);
$sentence1->execute();
$sentence1->bind_result($id, $product);
?>


    <html>
    <body>

    <table border="3">
    <tr>
    <td>ID of order</td>
    <td>ID of products from this order</td>
    </tr>


    <?php


while ($sentence1->fetch()) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $product . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

$sentence1->close();

?>
```

The problem is this SQL show repeatable times the number of id_order I want something like this:

```
id_order - id_product
    1        - 1
             - 2
             - 5
             - 6
    ____________
    2        - 4
             - 8
             - 14
    ____________
    3        - 1
```

The result I want is:

[image]

---

Another design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating over your result set in PHP, you can keep track of whether you encounter a new `id` value.  If so, then display it in a table cell, otherwise do not display it.

```
$id_prev = NULL;

while ($sentencie->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($id != $id_prev) {
        echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
        $id_prev = $id;
    }
    else {
        echo "<td></td>";    // you could try adding spaces here for padding
    }
    echo "<td>" . $product . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

As for the separator line, this is probably something which should be handled in your CSS/HTML layer.

**Update:**

It looks like your new requirement is to have the `id` table cells span multiple product rows.  One option would be to use the `rowspan` attribute of the table cell.  The trick here is that we need to iterate across an entire `id` before we know how many products there are.

```
$id_prev = NULL;
$products = array();

function displayRow($id, $products) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($products); $x++) {
        echo "<tr>";        
        if ($x == 0) {
            echo "<td rowspan=\"" . count($products) . "\">" . $id . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td>" . $products[$x] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

while ($sentencie->fetch()) {
    if ($id != $id_prev) {
        displayRow($id, $products);
        $products = array();
        $id_prev = $id;
    }
    array_push($products, $product);
}

// DON'T forget to call displayRow() one last time, to cover the final id
// appearing in your result set
displayRow($id_prev, $products);
```

Comment: another question how i can combine the tds? i will modify the question

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you want just a single column, then use a single `<td>` in each row.  As for spacing, if you use a monospaced font (e.g. Courier) then you try to line everything up nicely.

Comment: sorry for bad english, see the question

Comment: @VictorA. I don't have your script in front of me, so I can't test it.  Try adding spaces or other padding in the empty `<td>` for non-first row entries.

Comment: i do it this: .td{
    border:none;
}

Comment: It looks like you are asking for a table cell for each `id` which spans the entire product space.  This would be more work than my answer.  Why do you need this formatting?

Comment: a friend need throw the report of a list of products buyed, and he want see in a colum the number of order and another the products of that buy.

he want see no empty column. another way that he say to me is only create the table separation in the end of each order registry and add a list element to every product

Comment: adding new image to the question

Comment: Thanks a lot :), i triyed none borders but is seen not to good

Comment: I updated my answer.  Give it a shot, and if you have problems we can try to debug it.  Again, I don't have your code in front of me.

Comment: Errors appear: 

Line 10 : undefined offset 0 And array to string conversion, but dont worry my friend acccept the first model with border 0

Comment: @VictorA. My for loop had a slight problem with the condition.  Please try the updated code again.

Answer (score 1):

Here sql command .

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id_order, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_product ORDER BY id_product) AS child_id_list FROM orders group by id_order  ORDER BY id_order";
$sentence1 = $con->prepare($sql);
$sentence1->execute();
$sentence1->bind_result($id, $product);
```